# How to change CSS for specific category item?

Tags: magento-1.9, css

I am trying to change the css style of a specific item in my menu. My HTML code is this:

```
<ol class="nav-primary">

<li class="level0 nav-1 first parent"></li>

<li class="level0 nav-2"></li>

<li class="level0 nav-3"></li>

<li class="level0 nav-4 parent menu-active">

<li class="level1 nav-4-1 first last">

<a class="level1 " href="http://www.example.com"></a>
```

And the CSS I am trying (that probably needs tweaking) is this:

```
.nav-primary li.level1.nav-4-1 first {
color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS should be this

```
.nav-primary li.level1.nav-4-1.first a {
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that's not working though.

Comment: Nevermind; I had it sitting in the wrong screen resolution for the site! Eugh. No wonder I couldn't get it working. Thanks for your help!